# Why is 'static' needed in front of this variable?

Tags: static, hlsl

The documentation does not tell much about this behavior:

[Variable Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**static** *Mark a local variable so that it is initialized one time and persists between function calls. If the declaration does not include an initializer, the value is set to zero. A global variable marked static is not visible to an application.*

Can you explain why does removing the *static* modifier from matrices produces unexpected output ?

```
static float3x3 protanopia ={
    0.567f, 0.433f, 0.000f,
    0.558f, 0.442f, 0.000f,
    0.000f, 0.242f, 0.758f,
};
```

Normal result with *static* :

[image] [image]

Incorrect without *static*:

[image] [image]

Here's the complete code:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);

// new HLSL shader
// modify the comment parameters to reflect your shader parameters

/// <summary>Explain the purpose of this variable.</summary>
/// <minValue>0/minValue>
/// <maxValue>8</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
float Filter : register(C0);

static float3x3 norm ={
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

static float3x3 protanopia ={
    0.567f, 0.433f, 0.000f,
    0.558f, 0.442f, 0.000f,
    0.000f, 0.242f, 0.758f,
};

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{ 

    int filter = (int)abs(Filter);
    float3x3 mat;

    switch (filter)
    {
      case 0:
        mat = norm;
        break;
      case 1:
        mat=protanopia;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    float4 color = tex2D( input , uv.xy); 
    float3 rgb = {
        color.x * mat._m00 + color.y * mat._m01 + color.z * mat._m02,
        color.x * mat._m10 + color.y * mat._m11 + color.z * mat._m12,
        color.x * mat._m20 + color.y * mat._m21 + color.z * mat._m22
        };

    return float4(rgb,1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manage the memory of non-static variables yourself. Therefore when using static everything works as expected, since the compiler cares about reserving some memory where it can store the filter values. If the static is not present you have to manage the memory yourself - that means you have to retrieve the default value of the variable and copy it by hand to constant buffer for instance.