# float3x3 multiplication not working as expected in hlsl

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, shader, hlsl

After failing to implenet some vectors and matrix calculations in fragment shader, I tried to test basic matrix calculations in the vertex shader, just to be sure.

This works as expected:

```
uniform float4x4 _Identity4x4 = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
v2f vert (appdata v)
{
   v2f o;
   o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos( mul( v.vertex, _Identity4x4 ));
   ...
```

But this creates a havoc:

```
uniform float3x3 _Identity3x3 = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
v2f vert (appdata v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos( float4( mul( v.vertex.xyz, _Identity3x3 ), v.vertex.w));
    ...
```

I'm sure i'm missing something important, but can't figure it out or find some thing similar online.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Also the thing that you are doing can be simplified to `o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(float4(v.vertex.xyz, v.vertex.w));`

Comment: It shouldn't matter with identity matrices, but I'm pretty sure the matrix should be the first argument in the mul() call.  Otherwise the vector gets transformed by the transposed matrix.

Comment: @Daniel - I think it should be the same, but the second code snippet doesn't work and I wonder why.

Comment: @Louis Ingenthron - the documentation says the vector is transposed in that case. With an identity metrix I don't think it should matter

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the matrices need to be static. Not sure why the 4x4 works and the 3x3 doesn't...
A basic explanartion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621392/why-is-static-needed-in-front-of-this-variable).

Answer (score 0):

Matrix should go first (matrix multiplication is NOT commutative: A x B has a different result from B x A AND the vector is also a 3x1 matrix...)
So change your code to:
o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos( float4( mul( Identity3x3, v.vertex.xyz ), v.vertex.w));
Voila